# Why do I have to include the same dll twice in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, reference

Say I have a vs solution containing two projects: Project 1 is a core library used in multiple applications, and Project 2 is one of said applications, referencing Project 1.

In Project 1, I include the Microsoft SMO dll (through a NuGet package), used in an SQLTool class for some custom SQL Server operations to be re-used through our different applications.

What boggles me is this: when I call Project1.SQLTool from within Project 2 (which is why I am referencing Project 1 in the first place), I get missing reference exceptions and whatnot, until I also include the Microsoft SMO dll in Project 2. Isn't that redundant? Shouldn't it be either already included as a "nested" reference by the inclusion of Project 1, or not necessary at all since the actual code from the SMO dll is only used in the SQLTool class that is part of Project 1? The only code that requires SMO in Project 2 is the `SQLTool.MyMethod()` line, and that itself only uses part of the SMO library, which is huge.

Comment: Does your Project1 expose types from Microsoft SMO? Returns them from the public methods or accepts them as parameters?

Comment: Your c# application expects the SMO dll to be in the same folder as the project dll (or executable).  So if you have two projects and the project dlls are in different folders than the SMO dll need to be added twice unless the full path of the dll is specified.

Comment: @jdweng That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @GSerg : Why would the OP need to add the dll twice if the dll was in the same folder?  Which means the app is looking for the dll in two different folders.

Comment: @jdweng Because, as the OP explains, project 2 gives "Missing reference" errors when it refers to project 1 that uses the target library. So a reference to the same target library, in the same location, has to be added to the project 2 too to silence the error. Project 2 does not need to use the target library directly, yet the reference has to be added to silence the error. The OP is asking why that is.

Comment: @GSerg We are saying the same thing.  I said "unless the full path of the dll is specified".

Comment: @jdweng No, we are not saying the same thing. Even if the library force-referenced from Project 2 was a copy of the target library, from a different location, that would also silence the warning. The OP is asking how to make Project 2 *not* require a direct reference to the target library that it does not directly need. "Add the reference by full path" is not an answer to "how to avoid adding a reference".

Comment: @jdweng I have to agree with GSerg, because both of them, in my case, are in fact in the same location. (Hard-coded to C:\packages in this case, so the same files are being used)

Comment: @GSerg The method I am calling in Project 2 returns void and only takes in strings as parameters... However, I did write some other signatures for the same method name that do use SMO classes as parameters. I will try to see if removing those signatures or making them inaccessible removes the need for the reference.

Comment: @GSerg Good catch, setting the accessibility modifiers for the other signatures to internal rather than public seems to have fixed the requirement for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a method uses or returns types that are part of the dll (for example ServerConnection from SMO in my case), then projects using that method must also reference that dll.

If the method does not return or take in those types, **but other signatures of the method do**, then the dll reference is also required.

```
public void Connect(string serverName, string databaseName); // <-- Does not requires SMO dll
public void Connect(ServerConnection connection); // <-- Requires SMO dll due to ServerConnection
// Calling Connect(string,string) triggers the dll requirement due to 2nd signature
```

In my case, making those other signatures internal rather than public was trivial, and doing so removed the dll requirement on the project calling the method.

```
public void Connect(string serverName, string databaseName); // <-- Does not requires SMO dll
internal void Connect(ServerConnection connection); // <-- Internal signature not visible to other projects/assemblies
// Calling Connect(string,string) does not require the SMO dll to be referenced
```